# Command not found while executing curl in shell script

Tags: shell, curl

I am executing the below curl command in shell script. But I am getting command not found error. So wanted to check if I am making any mistake while executing it.

```
return = $(curl -s --location --request GET --url 'https://testurl.mywebsite.com/api/accts?Id=trst_id&var=test_var' --header 'type: app/test')

echo "data is: ${return}"
```

I am getting the error:

```
return: command not found
```

Kindly let me know if there is a problem with the way I am trying to execute the curl command.

Thank you.

Comment: are you sure curl is installed?

Comment: Whitespace matters in bash. Use `return=$(`.

Comment: @dan you are right.. white spaces where the issue.. thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like dan pointed out in comments, the extra whotespaces between the variable and command caused the issue. After removing extra whitespaces it worked.

return=$(curl -s --location --request GET --url 'https://testurl.mywebsite.com/api/accts?Id=trst_id&var=test_var' --header 'type: app/test')
echo "data is: ${return}"